# Simulate 500 error in Fiddler for R httr library

Tags: r, http, proxy, fiddler, httr

I have shiny web app and I want to test my code for 500 errors from API. My app is using httr library. I've set this in fiddler:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
    if (oSession.url.Contains("study.xml")) {
        oSession.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseCode = 500;
        oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Foo", "Bar");
    }
}
```

and in R code I have this:

```
  path <- paste0(
    url,
    "/study.xml/", .session$sid, "/analysis_data"
  )
  res <- GET(path, use_proxy("127.0.0.1", 8888))
  print(paste(path, res$status_code))
  print(json(headers(res)))
  if (res$status_code == 500) {
    # handler error
    stop("error 500")
  }
```

Even that I have 500 for the response in Fiddler, in R I have 200, the header is set correctly and when the page return 404 I get 404 response.

Is there other way to simulate 500 error code in fiddler? I find Fiddler script to be simplest, because I don't need to fiddle with Fiddler interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found It, I needed to use:

```
oSession.oRequest.FailSession(500, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked this request");
```